# IE.Navigate to wait until URL changes

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, scripting

I'm trying to make an script that enter credentials of a web but I've noticed when I place the form's URL(https://accounts.sap.com/saml2/idp/sso/accounts.sap.com) directly in the browser it displays a message that says:

> ERROR Identity Provider could not process the authentication request
>   received. Delete your browser cache and stored cookies, and restart
>   your browser. If you continue to experience issues, send an e-mail to
>   sso@sap.com

But if i type https://launchpad.support.sap.com/ in the browser it relaunch the same URL with no error message.

this is the script I'm using:

```
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/softwarecenter"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("j_username").value = "USERNAME"
        .getElementByID("j_password").value = "PASSWORD"
        .getElementsByName("frmLogin")(0).Submit
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

But the script does not wait for the URL to change and search for the Elements.

Does anybody know how to wait until the URL change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their server uses redirects. (f12>Networking tab in IE). You should navigate to 
https://accounts.sap.com/

```
IE.Navigate("https://accounts.sap.com")
```

you should also make sure that the "Remember Me" checkbox is turned off, so that the website cookie does not try to automatically log you in the next time you run the script.

```
.getElementById("rememberme").checked = false;
```

You can use the IE dev tool (f12) to delete the site cookie each time you run your script.

Ideally you want to 'logoff' of their website each testing cycle, so that each time you run your script a new session on their server is created.